# keep textarea default value with html break tag using nl2br

Tags: php, html

I'm stuck in figuring this out. I used `nl2br()` to keep the line break (turn new line into html break tag), example I have value `hello <br/> yeah` in my textarea, but when I `echo` it to a textarea value it's echoed as:

```
hello <br/ >\r\nyeah
```

instead of:

```
hello
yeah
```

This is the text area code I get from inspect element:

```
<textarea placeholder="Max 40.000 Huruf" style="overflow-x:none;width:99%;height:300px;" type="text" name="jawaban" maxlength="40000">
hello&lt;br /&gt;\r\nyeah
</textarea>
```

Why is this happening?

screenshot:

[image: error]

I'm not skilled at javascript.

and if there's previous post / php method that could fix this, tell me.

Comment: What did you expect? You converted all the line breaks to `<br/>`.

Comment: i was mean if it's echoed it would keep the line break

Comment: Then why did you use `nl2br()`?

Comment: i don't know the method